# Identifying a capacitor with marking K1G 103J

Tags: capacitor, components, identification

I need help identifying a throw-hole capacitor, orange/brown color, with markings:

```
`K1G`
`103J`
```

[image]

I suspect that it is a KEMET part, but they might have obsoleted the part, as they have no posted datasheet for it. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://kaizerpowerelectronics.dk/theory/capacitor-code-table/) and [this](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/data/capacitor/capacitor-markings.php) webpages, 103J would mean 10 * 1000 pF = 10000 pF = 10 nF with 5% tolerance.

K1G maybe refers to voltage. Maybe it is a value between 1H and 1J (50 VDC < Voltage < 63 VDC)?